# How do I generalize calling a list of functions in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, chain-of-responsibility

I have the following code which allows me to instantiate and then call a list of `void()` functions.

(I am using https://github.com/philsquared/Catch for unit testing if you wish to compile and run this code).

```
#include "catch.hpp"

#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class ChainOfResponsibility : public std::vector<std::function<void()> >, public std::function<void()>
{
public:
    void operator()() const
    {
        for(std::vector<std::function<void()> >::const_iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it) {
            (*it)();
        }
    }
};

TEST_CASE("ChainOfResponsibility calls its members when invoked")
{
    bool test_function_called = false;
    std::function<void()> test_function = [&]()
    {
        test_function_called = true;
    };

    ChainOfResponsibility object_under_test;

    object_under_test.push_back(test_function);
    object_under_test();

    REQUIRE(test_function_called);
}
```

My question is how do I template the `ChainOfResponsibility` class to accept functions with a different (but consistent) signature?

For example, consider a `ChainOfResponsibility<void(int)>` or a `ChainOfResponsibility<ReturnClass(Argument1Class, Argument2Class)>`.

For the sake of argument, lets say that the second example returns the value returned by the last member in the chain, or the default value for ReturnClass if the chain is empty.

Also, if the STL already contains a template class that achieves this, then I would prefer to use it over my home-grown class.

Comment: Since you are using `std::function`, your code requires C++11, so you could also use `auto` and range-based `for`. That would allow much cleaner code.

Comment: why do you need to derive from `std::vector` and `std::function`?

Comment: @el.pescado Thanks for the tip! I haven't programmed in C++ in some time. So I'm not aware of the newer features.

Comment: @Gruffalo I derive from std::vector to get all the vector operations for free (like push_back, insert, and swap). I derive from std::function so that instances are nestable. If there is a better way, I am all ears...

Comment: @Gruffalo Turns out, I don't need to derive from std::function to make instances nestable. Thanks for the eye opener!

Comment: @spierepf I don't know all your details of course but I do think there's a better way, check the last suggestion in Akira's answer. all you need is a function, inheritance is massively overused in general

Answer (score 7):

Your specific "discard all the intermediate results" is also fairly simple, but I think it's a bad idea.

```
template<typename Ret, typename ... Args>
class ChainOfResponsibility
{
    std::vector<std::function<Ret(Args...)> > chain;
public:
    Ret operator()(Args ... args) const
    {
        Ret value;
        for(auto & func : chain) {
            value = func(args...);
        }
        return value;
    }
};
```

`void` has to be treated on it's own

```
template<typename ... Args>
class ChainOfResponsibility<void, Args...>
{
    std::vector<std::function<void(Args...)> > chain;
public:
    void operator()(Args ... args) const
    {
        for(auto & func : chain) {
            func(args...);
        }
    }
};
```

Note that deriving from `std::` types is a bad idea, especially `std::function`, which is a type-erasing callable, not "the base of all callables". You can simply provide an `operator()`

options for improving the non-void case:

```
    // fold the results
    template <typename BinaryFunction>
    Ret operator()(Args ... args, BinaryFunction add, Ret init) const
    {
        for(auto & func : chain) {
            init = add(init, func(args...));
        }
        return init;
    }

    // return a vector
    template <typename BinaryFunction>
    std::vector<Ret> operator()(Args ... args) const
    {
        std::vector<Ret> results(chain.size());
        for(auto & func : chain) {
            results.push_back(func(args...));
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as a base class, using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is sufficent. The template `ChainOfResponsibility` can use the same template paramter list as the `std::function` like follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

template<typename>
class ChainOfResponsibility;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
class ChainOfResponsibility<R(Args...)> :
        public std::vector<std::function<R(Args...)>> {
public:
    R operator()(const Args&... args) {
        R result {};

        for(auto it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); ++it)
            result = (*it)(args...);

        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
    ChainOfResponsibility<std::string(int, int)> tester;

    tester.push_back([](int a, int b)->std::string {
        return std::to_string(a + b);
    });

    std::cout << tester(4, 2) << std::endl;
}
```

Anyway, using `std::vector` only is good enoug for the problem you described. If the content of the overloaded `operator()` is nothing special, you can change my example above as follows:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::function<std::string(int, int)>> tester;

    tester.push_back([](int a, int b)->std::string {
        return std::to_string(a + b);
    });

    std::string result;

    for(auto& test_fn : tester)
        result = test_fn(4, 2);

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

You also can write a function template instead of overloading the `operator()`:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
R perform(const std::vector<std::function<R(Args...)>>& functions,
        const Args&... args) {
    R result {};
    for(auto& test_fn : functions)
        result = test_fn(4, 2);
    return result;
}
```